# Custom hook when taking data in next render lost data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

I made a hook useSendFormData , when i use it i get Invalid hook call.

- Hook takes
- data from SubmitForm
- url:string,
- method: post or put
- success: success message if it was success
- id: not required but if item has id i is added to api call.
- auth default false

Problem is it loses data on renders I don't know how to describe it better so I made console.log ss

As you can see on second call I get data but later it's gone...

[image: problem image]

My code for this custom hook:

```
    const sendFormData = async ({
    formData,
    url,
    method,
    success,
    id,
    auth = false,
  }) => {
    const setPartData = (partialData) => setData({ ...data, ...partialData });
    try {
      let response;
      if (method === "post") {
        response = await axios.post(
          `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
          formData
        );
      } else if (method === "put") {
        response = auth
          ? await fetchContext.authAxios.post(
              `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
              formData
            )
          : await axios.post(
              `${SERVER_API}api/v1/${url}/${id ?? ""}`,
              formData
            );
      }
      setPartData({
        data: response.data,
        loading: false,
        success,
        error: null,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      const { data } = err.response;
      setPartData({
        error: data.error,
        success: null,
        loading: false,
      });
    }
    return data;
  };

  return {
    sendFormData,
  };
};
```

And where is use it , it takes data from SubmitForm and make api call with it,as you can see in ss i get there undefined:

```
const { sendFormData } = useSendFormData()


const handleForm = async (info) => {
  // here you have your response.data returned
  const data = await sendFormData({
    formData: info,
    url: "auth/forgot-password",
    method: "post",
    success: "A password reset message has been sent to your email",
  });

  console.log(data);

  reset();
};
```

If you could help that would be awesome. If you have any optimatizaion hints for this hook please tell me.Thanks for your time.

**Edit: Edit hook but doesnt return data value at the end**

Comment: Can you clarify specifically what causes the **renders**, the ones that you **lose data**? Is it related to the `reset()` call at the end of `handleForm`? What does `reset()` actually do?

Comment: reset() is from react-hook-form and its only reset form values after submition

Comment: I think it might just be a simple confusion of variables. Take note that `sendFormData` function is only returning `undefined` regardless of a successful / error api call. So the `data` in `data = await sendFormData()` will always be `undefined` (which is in your console logs). The console logs showing `data` with actual stuff are likely from the `console.log(data)` called within `useSendFormData` hook, just before returning the data itself. I recommend renaming the variables a little, and double checking what functions are returning what kinds of things.

Comment: made chages but doesnt help

Comment: @98sean98 add edits to code but steal doesnt work

Comment: Do you think you can make a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of some sort to reproduce the issue?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-surf-wrvjw

Comment: the only reason i make this coustom hook to be my components more dry .I think this is a good approach.Also sandbox is simplifyied...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```js
const setPartData = (partialData) => setData({ ...data, ...partialData });
```

should be changed to

```js
const setPartData = (partialData) => setData(data => ({ ...data, ...partialData }));
```

**Explanation**

`setState` callback can take either the new state (what you have done), or another callback (what should be done). You should pass a callback like so, to make sure that multiple calls of `setPartialData(someData)` within `sendFormData` uses the latest `data` state to update itself (combining `partialData`). This approach is necessary as `const sendFormData = () => {}` is declared, the `data` variable used within is whatever `data` was outside the function block (from `const [data, setData] = useState()` ). This `data` is not updated as `sendFormData()` runs, instead only on the end of a component render cycle.

In other words,

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

const sendFormData = () => {
  const setPartData = (partialData) => setData({ ...data, ...partialData });
  setPartData(data1); // combines with initialData
  setPartData(data2); // combines with initialData as well
}
```

*Note that where you declare `const setPartData` does not matter, as long as it has access to the `data` scope.*

On the other hand,

```js
const setPartData = (partialData) => setData(data => ({ ...data, ...partialData }));
```

uses the latest `data` state when `setData()` needs to run, by accessing it through the internal callback.

Since the hook you built can return the `data` state, once it is updated correctly, you can now use it like this in a better manner.

```js
// App.js
const {data, sendFormData} = useSendFormData();

const sendAction = async (arg) => await sendFormData(arg);

return <>
  <button onClick={sendAction}>send data</button>
  { data.success || someCondition ? data : null }
</>
```

---

It's probably not a good idea to reinvent the wheel when [this swr library](https://github.com/vercel/swr) exists, but I commend your effort in trying to make code DRY.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer,but i have a question can i only return state(data) in sendFormData not in useSendFormData?

Comment: Yes. Just `return { data, sendFormData }` at the end of `useSendFormData`. But beware that the `data` state is not shared across multiple instances of `useSendFormData()` in different components. If you need to share `data`, either use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#:~:text=React%20Redux%20is%20the%20official,the%20store%20to%20update%20data.).

Comment: Returning `data` for the hook you made should help you avoid declaring `const [data, setData] = useState()` everytime, in different components, if you want to use `sendFormData`.